# What does -cp mean in the terminal when running a .jar file?

Tags: java, syntax, jar, terminal

I have to get some kinks out of a shell script for work, and one of the line looks like this:

Comment: Check out the usage docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-cp: this is the classpath`

This is the set of classes that are used when running a specific class.

In your example; `OrganT.Tune.Mix OrganT` must be a class in the classpath (in this case, inside the `OrganT.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation, can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint - under linux and mac you can use the

`man <command goes here>`

comman in the terminal/shell to display all parameters and usage information available for the specific command.

Answer (score 0):

`-cp` stands for classpath. The CLASSPATH variable is one way to tell applications, including the JDK tools, where to look for user classes.

```
java -classpath .;YourJarFile.jar
```

---

I think you want to run a script for including the class path and execute the jar.

- To do this in any text editor type `java -jar YourJarFile.jar` and save it, with extention (anyName.sh) assuming you have got linux flavour. Make it executable using the command chmod 775 anyName.sh
- For windows type `java -jar YourJarFile.jar`, and save it with extention (anyName.bat)